# regular expression for date format itself in XSD pattern restriction

Tags: regex, xml, xsd, xsd-1.0

I am trying to make a regular expression for date format in XSD 1.0 pattern restriction.

I want to check if the date 'format' is invalid, NOT date value.

Date format I want to check are;

```
Year:  YYYY or YY
Month: MM or M or MMM or MMMM
Day: D or DD
and has zero or unbounded of . / ; (just space) ! @
```

For example, below value is vaild;

```
MMM. D. YYYY
MM/DD/YYYY
DD/MM.YYYY
YYMM DD
```

below is not valid;

```
dd%mmYYYY
20140404
YYYY-MM-YYYY-DD
```

I made a regular expression but have a problem. It checks `'YYYY-MM-YYYY'` as valid (YYYY is repeated)

```
([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(YYYY|YY|M|MM|MMM|MMMM|D|DD)[!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*)+
```

How can I make the regular expression check if there is only one `YYYY|YY|M|..D|DD?`

XML schema 1.0 / Xercers-J

Comment: I believe this is incredibly impractical to do without lookaheads or some programming (if it's even possible) - the problem is that without those things, you would have to outline every possible *valid* combination of the tokens (`YYYY`, `DD`, `M`, etc), with whatever characters you want to allow in between put into the pattern in between the tokens... it might very well be less than 8^8, (maybe you could combine the checks for the `M`s into `M{1,4}`), but the regex might not fit into the answer length limit - not entirely sure... If it has to be in the XSD, you might be out of luck.

Comment: @Code Jockey I agree with you. date format itself is portion of programming language rather than XSD. However it should be done in XSD in this time oops. Thank you for your advice anyway.

Comment: Seems like it was possible and it was _ALMOST_ a reasonable regex... still not the best to use it without programming support whenever that is possible, though - and n.b. that the length and complexity would increase exponentially if one were to try to add time values (`H`/`HH`, `m`/`mm`, etc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, as much as it puts a bad taste in my mouth to even paste this into the answer box, I think this may be what you're looking for (your scroll bar is going to get a reasonable workout today)...

```
(([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(YY(YY)?([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(M{1,4}([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(DD?)?)?)?)?))|([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(YY(YY)?([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(DD?([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(M{1,4})?)?)?)?))|([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(M{1,4}([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(DD?([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(YY(YY)?)?)?)?)?))|([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(M{1,4}([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(YY(YY)?([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(DD?)?)?)?)?))|([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(DD?([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(YY(YY)?([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(M{1,4})?)?)?)?))|([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(DD?([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(M{1,4}([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(YY(YY)?)?)?)?)?)))[!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*
```

Got all that? This is it broken down into the 9 possibilities of the order in which the token types (Year, Month or Day) can appear (if I understand you correctly)... I can explain if you ask, but don't wanna waste time if nobody is interested - even someone stumbling on this answer and commenting and asking for an explanation is enough - just let me know.

```
(

([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(YY(YY)?([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(M{1,4}([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(DD?)?)?)?)?))|

([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(YY(YY)?([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(DD?([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(M{1,4})?)?)?)?))|

([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(M{1,4}([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(DD?([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(YY(YY)?)?)?)?)?))|

([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(M{1,4}([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(YY(YY)?([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(DD?)?)?)?)?))|

([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(DD?([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(YY(YY)?([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(M{1,4})?)?)?)?))|

([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(DD?([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(M{1,4}([!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*(YY(YY)?)?)?)?)?))

)[!@#%_\-=`~,\.\/;: ]*
```